# Replace with NA in the whole dataframe using wildcards

Tags: r, dataframe, replace, wildcard, na

I have a dataframe df like this

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | x1A | 9 |
| 8 | x3 | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | x4Z |

I want to replace all values starting with `X` by `NA`. The result should be

| Col1 | Col2 | Col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 5 |
| 6 | NA | 9 |
| 8 | NA | 7 |
| 5 | 3 | NA |

I tried different solutions with no success:

```
df[-grep(pattern = "X^",df),]    
df %>% mutate_all(~na_if(.,"X*"))    
df%>% mutate_all(~na_if(.,matches("X*")))    
df %>% mutate_all(~na_if(.,glob2rx("X*")))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that according to the `na_if` help page, `na_if(x, y)` only replaces values if `x` and `y` are exactly equal. There is no partial matching or support for boolean values.

You could use `if_else` instead

```
df %>% mutate_all(~if_else(grepl("^X", .), NA, .))
```

Note that this will not change the class of the column. If you read in data that had an "X" that data would have been read in as a character vector. So replacing those values with NA will still leave the column as a character vector.

Comment: Of course, the docs say that `mutate_all` has been superseded. I still find the `mutate_all` syntax a bit easier, but I'm guessing it will be deprecated soon?

Comment: It's not necessarily the case that superseded will turn into deprecated https://lifecycle.r-lib.org/articles/stages.html#superseded. It just may not get "updates" in the future. I doubt it will go away anytime soon.

Comment: That's interesting - thanks. This seems to imply that superseded functions are, if anything, _less likely_ to be deprecated. I wonder if `mutate_all` is less efficient, or whether the dplyr authors just want a consistent interface, to move away from maintaining all those scoped verbs.

Answer (score 5):

Using `as.numeric` will automatically convert anything starting with an "X" into an `NA`, whilst converting everything else into a number. The only drawback is that a warning is emitted when parsing fails, so a (quiet) one-liner tidyverse solution would be:

```r
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~suppressWarnings(as.numeric(.x))))
#>   Col1 Col2 Col3
#> 1    1    2    5
#> 2    6   NA    9
#> 3    8   NA    7
#> 4    5    3    4
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Your solution is great if the expected result is only made of numeric values. In my case, the resulting dataframe includes some non-numeric values like 1A and 4Z. I edited the example with values x1A and x4Z to take this feature into account..

Answer (score 4):

In base R, using `lapply()` should do the trick:

```
df[] <- lapply(df[], as.numeric) # building off @Allan Cameron's excellent answer

# or using `grep`
df[] <- lapply(df[], \(x){x[grep("X", x)] <- NA; as.numeric(x)})

# or You could also use an alternative `apply` approach:
df[apply(df, 2, \(x) grepl("X", x))] <- NA
```

All are base R approaches and return:

```
#  Col1 Col2 Col3
#1    1    2    5
#2    6   NA    9
#3    8   NA    7
#4    5    3    4
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text = "Col1 Col2 Col3
1 2 5
6 X1 9
8 X3 7
5 3 4", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, please try the below code

```r
library(tidyverse)

data %>% mutate(across(starts_with('Col'), ~ ifelse(grepl('^X', .), NA, .)))

  Col1 Col2 Col3
1    1    2    5
2    6 <NA>    9
3    8 <NA>    7
4    5    3    4
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
# Columns remain character
df[apply(df, 2, startsWith, "X")] <- NA
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1    1    2    5
# 2    6 <NA>    9
# 3    8 <NA>    7
# 4    5    3    4
```

Similar to @AllanCameron's answer (this assumes your entire data frame is the same class):

```
# Coerce everything to numeric
data.frame(`class<-`(as.matrix(df), "numeric"))
#   Col1 Col2 Col3
# 1    1    2    5
# 2    6   NA    9
# 3    8   NA    7
# 4    5    3    4
```